# Error During Upload in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, nativescript

I am trying to upload captured image from my nativescript to server using wen api which i created in c#(asp.net) api working fine on postman but while I am uploading from mobile my android file uploader giving me error "Error During Upload"

web API code

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("PostUserImage")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUserImage()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
           //     response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    int MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 1; //Size = 1 MB  

                    IList<string> AllowedFileExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };
                    var ext = postedFile.FileName.Substring(postedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                    var extension = ext.ToLower();
                    if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(extension))
                    {
                        var message = string.Format("Please Upload image of type .jpg,.gif,.png.");
                        dict.Add("error", message);
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                    }
                    else if (postedFile.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
                    {

                        var message = string.Format("Please Upload a file upto 1 mb.");
                        dict.Add("error", message);
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Userimage/" + postedFile.FileName + extension);

                        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                    }
                }

                var message1 = string.Format("Image Updated Successfully.");
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, message1); ;
            }
            var res = string.Format("Please Upload a image.");
            dict.Add("error", res);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var res = ex.Message;
            dict.Add("error", res);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
        }
    }
```

Nativescript Upload code

```
 var bghttpModule = require("nativescript-background-http");
 var session = bghttpModule.session("image-upload");
 var application = require("application");
 var fs = require("file-system");
 var camera = require("nativescript-camera");
 var imageSource = require('image-source');
 var uiEnums = require("ui/enums");
exports.onCapture = function(args)
{ 
  var dialogs = require("ui/dialogs");
   dialogs.action({
  message: "Select Option to Attach Image",
  cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
  actions: ["Camera", "Gallary"]
  }).then(function (result) {
  console.log("Dialog result: " + result); 
  if(result == "Camera"){
      //Do action1
      console.log("Camera selected");
      if(imagecontainer.imageSource!=null)
      {
          imagecontainer.imageSource=null;
      }

  camera.takePicture({
   width: 200, height: 200, keepAspectRatio: true, saveToGallery: false
  })   
.then(function (imageAsset) {
    console.log("Result is an image asset instance"); 
    console.log("Image taken!");

     filepath = fs.path.join(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath(), "Test.jpeg");

    imageAsset.getImageAsync(image => {

    imagecontainer.imageSource = imageSource.fromNativeSource(image);
   (imagecontainer.imageSource).saveToFile(filepath, uiEnums.ImageFormat.jpeg);

    });
    var request = {
        url: "http://HostAddress/WebAPI/Sample/PostUserImage",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "undefined",
            "File-Name": "Test.jpeg"
        },
        description: "{ 'uploading': " + "Test.jpeg" + " }"
    };

    var task = session.uploadFile(filepath, request)
    task.on("progress", logEvent);
    task.on("error", logEvent);
    task.on("complete", logEvent);
    console.log("file path;;;;;;:"+filepath);
    function logEvent(e) {
        console.log("----------------");
        console.log('Status: ' + e.eventName);
        // console.log(e.object);
        if (e.totalBytes !== undefined) {
            console.log('current bytes transfered: ' + e.currentBytes);
            console.log('Total bytes to transfer: ' + e.totalBytes);
        }
    } 
    return task;

}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
});
  }else if(result == "Gallary"){
      if(imagecontainer.imageSource!=null)
      {
          imagecontainer.imageSource=null;
      }
      //Do action2
      var items;
      var imagepicker = require("nativescript-imagepicker");
      var context = imagepicker.create({
          mode: "single"
      });
      context.authorize()
          .then(function() {
              return context.present();
          })
          .then(function(selection) {
            filepath = fs.path.join(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath(), "Test"+ ".jpg");
              selection.forEach(function(selected) {
                selected.getImage({ maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200, aspectRatio: 'fill' })
                .then((imageSourceS) => {
                    imagecontainer.imageSource = imageSourceS;
                    imageSourceS.saveToFile(filepath, uiEnums.ImageFormat.jpeg);
                });
                var request = {
                    url: "http://HostAddress/WebAPI/Sample/PostUserImage",
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "undefined",
                        "File-Name": "Test.jpg"
                    },
                    description: "{ 'uploading': " + "Test.jpg" + " }"
                };
                var task = session.uploadFile(filepath, request)
                task.on("progress", logEvent);
                task.on("error", logEvent);
                task.on("complete", logEvent);

                function logEvent(e) {
             //       console.log("----------------");
              //      console.log('Status: ' + e.eventName);
                    // console.log(e.object);
                    if (e.totalBytes !== undefined) {
                        console.log('current bytes transfered: ' + e.currentBytes);
                        console.log('Total bytes to transfer: ' + e.totalBytes);
                    }
                }
           //     console.log("file path;;;;;;:"+filepath);
           //     console.log("pic selected");
           return task;
              });

          }).catch(function (e) {
          console.log(e);
      });
  }


  });

 };
```

### Output

JS: Result is an image asset instance

JS: Image taken!

JS: file path;;;;;;:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Test.jpeg

JS: in dock receive
JS:    ---------------- 
JS: Status: progress 
JS: current bytes transfered: 4096 
JS: Total bytes to transfer: 92558 
JS:----------------
JS: Status: progress 
JS: current bytes transfered: 92558 
JS: Total bytes    to transfer: 92558
JS: ---------------- 
JS: Status: complete

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the saveToFile() is being done inside an async function.

```html
selected.getImage({ maxWidth: 200 }).then((imageSourceS) => 
{
    console.log("A");
});
console.log("B");
// upload code
```

This is how your code is structured.

It'll print B and then A.